# Calculate a value with multiple columns in a each record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to perform a calculation in a select query on below table:

| MainPrice | Mw01 | Price01 | Mw02 | Price02 | Mw03 | Price03 | Mw04 | Price04 | Mw05 | Price05 | Mw06 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22.9 | 379 | 10.92 | 464 | 12.42 | 464 | 16.03 | 521 | 16.03 | 521 | 63.37 | 521 |

In this table, I have a column `MainPrice` which I need to check if it is less than or equal to `Price01`, `Price02`, `Price03` through `Price06`.

Example considering first record:

```
MainPrice <= Price01 (22.99 <= 10.92)
```

is false, so then it should next check against `Price02`, which is again false.

```
MainPrice <= Price05 (22.99 <= 63.37)
```

satisfies the condition so I need to pick `Price05` & `MW05` with previous values which is are `Price04` & `Price05`.

So now have values `MW05`, `Price05`, `MW04`, `Price04` & `MainPrice`.

With these values I need to do a calculation using this formula:

```
(((MainPrice - Price04) * (MW05 - MW04)) / (Price05 - Price04)) + MW04  

(((22.99 - 16.03) * (521 - 521)) / (63.37 - 16.03)) + 521
```

Is it possible to do this in one select query?

My approach: I'm doing using cases and created a function which will return a calculated value.

```
SELECT
    CalculatedMW = CASE 
                       WHEN Price01 >= MainPrice 
                           THEN MW01 
                       WHEN Price02 >= MainPrice 
                           THEN dbo.calculate(MainPrice, MW02, MW01, Price02, Price01)  
                       WHEN Price03 >= MainPrice  
                           THEN dbo.calculate(MainPrice, MW03, MW02, Price03, Price02)  
                       WHEN Price04 >= MainPrice  
                           THEN dbo.calculate(MainPrice, MW04, MW03, Price04, Price03)  
                       WHEN Price05 >= MainPrice 
                           THEN dbo.calculate(MainPrice, MW05, MW04, Price05, Price04)  
                       WHEN Price06 >= MainPrice    
                       ELSE 0 
                   END 
FROM
    dbo.Pricing
```

Comment: This kind of calculation belongs to the business layer. This is a future maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Please do not post image, use text instead

Comment: @Tarik Yes Tarik the database is not normalized and client says do all logic in store procs only. I have thought all the approaches. How about while loop ?

Comment: @DaveKing Could you please copy the data as text, not image.

Comment: I suggest you create sql functions to improve reusability. I think sql server allows to create table based functions and other such features to avoid repeated hardcoding.

Answer (score 3):

You can unpivot pairs of (Price__, MW__) and select your parameters with CROSS APPLY

```
select MainPrice, 
  ((MainPrice - pp) * (m - mm)) / (p - pp) + mm  res 
from yourtable
cross apply (
select top(1) *
    from (
      select *, lag(p) over(order by n) pp, lag(m) over(order by n) mm
      from (
        values 
          (1, Price01, MW01),
          (2, Price02, MW02),
          (3, Price03, MW03),
          (4, Price04, MW04),
          (5, Price05, MW05),
          (6, Price06, MW06)
        ) t(n,p,m)
    ) t
    where t.p <= MainPrice
    order by n 
) t
```

Not sure what if the first pair satisfies the condition t.p <= MainPrice. You may need to change your formula for this terminal case.

Answer (score 0):

One way is first to UNPIVOT the data, and it's a kind of more complicated as we have two pairs of columns. So, having this data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Pricing;

CREATE TABLE #Pricing 
(
    [MainPrice] MONEY NOT NULL,
    [Price01] MONEY NOT NULL,
    [MW01] INT NOT NULL,
    [Price02] MONEY NOT NULL,
    [MW02] INT NOT NULL,
    [Price03] INT NOT NULL,
    [MW03] INT NOT NULL,
    [Price04] MONEY NOT NULL,
    [MW04] INT NOT NULL,
    [Price05] MONEY NOT NULL,
    [MW05] INT NOT NULL,
    [Price06] MONEY NOT NULL,
    [MW06] INT NOT NULL,
    [Price07] MONEY NOT NULL,
    [MW07] INT NOT NULL,
    [Price08] MONEY NOT NULL,
    [MW08] INT NOT NULL,
    [Price09] MONEY NOT NULL,
    [MW09] INT NOT NULL,
    [Price10] MONEY NOT NULL,
    [MW10] INT NOT NULL,
    [Price11] MONEY NOT NULL,
    [MW11] INT NOT NULL,
    [Price12] MONEY NOT NULL,
    [MW12] INT NOT NULL
);

-- Insert data
INSERT INTO #Pricing (MainPrice, Price01, MW01, Price02, MW02, Price03, MW03, Price04, MW04, Price05, MW05, Price06, MW06, Price07, MW07, Price08, MW08, Price09, MW09, Price10, MW10, Price11, MW11, Price12, MW12)
VALUES 
(100.00, 50.00, 2, 70.00, 5, 500.00, 3, 90.00, 10, 80.00, 8, 70.00, 6, 50.00, 2, 60.00, 4, 80.00, 7, 90.00, 10, 100.00, 12, 80.00, 9),
(120.00, 60.00, 3, 80.00, 6, 600.00, 4, 100.00, 11, 90.00, 9, 80.00, 7, 60.00, 3, 70.00, 5, 90.00, 8, 100.00, 11, 120.00, 13, 100.00, 10),
(140.00, 70.00, 4, 90.00, 7, 700.00, 5, 110.00, 12, 100.00, 10, 90.00, 8, 70.00, 4, 80.00, 6, 100.00, 9, 110.00, 12, 140.00, 14, 120.00, 11),
(160.00, 80.00, 5, 100.00, 8, 800.00, 6, 120.00, 13, 110.00, 11, 100.00, 9, 80.00, 5, 90.00, 7, 110.00, 10, 120.00, 13, 160.00, 15, 140.00, 12);
```

We can use the code above:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT MainPrice
              ,Price01,Price02,Price03,Price04,Price05,Price06,Price07,Price08,Price09,Price10,Price11,Price12
              ,'Price' AS [type]
        FROM #Pricing
        UNION ALL
        SELECT MainPrice
              ,CAST(MW01 AS MONEY), CAST(MW02 AS MONEY), CAST(MW03 AS MONEY), CAST(MW04 AS MONEY), CAST(MW05 AS MONEY), CAST(MW06 AS MONEY), CAST(MW07 AS MONEY), CAST(MW08 AS MONEY), CAST(MW09 AS MONEY), CAST(MW10 AS MONEY), CAST(MW11 AS MONEY), CAST(MW12 AS MONEY)
              ,'MW'
        FROM #Pricing
    ) DS
    UNPIVOT
    (
        [value] FOR [Column] IN ([Price01], [Price02], [Price03], [Price04], [Price05], [Price06], [Price07], [Price08], [Price09], [Price10], [Price11], [Price12])    
    ) PVT
)
SELECT DS1.MainPrice
      ,DS1.[value] AS [Price]
      ,DS2.[value] AS [Mw]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DS1.MainPrice ORDER BY DS1.[column]) AS [RowID]
FROM DataSource DS1
INNER JOIN DataSource DS2
    ON DS1.[MainPrice] = DS2.MainPrice
    AND RIGHT(DS1.[Column], 2) = RIGHT(DS2.[Column], 2)
WHERE DS1.[type] ='price'
    AND DS2.[type]= 'MW'
ORDER BY DS1.MainPrice, [RowID]
```

to get this:

[image]

Now, we are only interested in rows where `MainPrice` is smaller then `Price`. So, just adding `WHERE` clause:

```
...
SELECT DS1.MainPrice
      ,DS1.[value] AS [Price]
      ,DS2.[value] AS [Mw]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DS1.MainPrice ORDER BY DS1.[column]) AS [RowID]
FROM DataSource DS1
INNER JOIN DataSource DS2
    ON DS1.[MainPrice] = DS2.MainPrice
    AND RIGHT(DS1.[Column], 2) = RIGHT(DS2.[Column], 2)
WHERE DS1.[type] ='price'
    AND DS2.[type]= 'MW'
    AND DS1.MainPrice < DS1.[value]
```

and get:

[image]

Now, you can perform your calculations. But, there can be several rows for which the criteria is true. A  way to handle this is the above to be in subquery and filter only where RowID=1. Alternative is something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES DS1.MainPrice
                      ,DS1.[value] AS [Price]
                      ,DS2.[value] AS [Mw]
FROM DataSource DS1
INNER JOIN DataSource DS2
    ON DS1.[MainPrice] = DS2.MainPrice
    AND RIGHT(DS1.[Column], 2) = RIGHT(DS2.[Column], 2)
WHERE DS1.[type] ='price'
    AND DS2.[type]= 'MW'
    AND DS1.MainPrice < DS1.[value]
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DS1.MainPrice ORDER BY DS1.[column]) ASC
```